# Make automatic analyse using for to 100x

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, igraph

I have 100 matrix, I need do same analyse for all.

```
###DADOSEXEMPLO##
vetor <- c(1, 5, 3, 8, 2, 9, 3, 2:15, 1, 5, 3, 6, 5, 9, 3 )
matrixnet(vetor, 7, 7)
matrixnet<-matrix(vetor, 7, 7)
matcor <- cor(matrixnet, method = "spearman")

 matrixnetwork = graph.adjacency(matcor, mode="undirected", weighted 
 = TRUE, 
 add.colnames=NULL, diag=FALSE)
plot(matrixnetwork)
matrix
```

Here I utilize boot with permute in igraph pacote, I don't know if it is correct!! Help

```
###BOOT
N <- 7L
set.seed(2023)
R <- 100L
BIPERMUT<- vector("list", length = R)
for(i in seq.int(R)) {
  indices <- sample(N, replace = TRUE)
  BIPERMUT[[i]] <- permute(matrixnetwork, 
 sample(vcount(matrixnetwork)))  
##ANALYSE
degree(BIPERMUT[[1]], normalized = FALSE, loops = FALSE)
```

I try, but this not run the analyse 100x, this resample 100x:

```
for(i in seq.int(R)) {
indices <- sample(N, replace = TRUE)
 boot_degree= degree(g_boot_list[[i]], normalized = FALSE, loops = 
  FALSE)
```

I try this form too for boot in matrix:

```
 ######Matrix permutation#####
 N <- 7L
 set.seed(2023)
 R <- 100L
 BIPERMUT<- vector("list", length = R)
 for(i in seq.int(R)) {
   indices <- sample(N, replace = TRUE)
   BIPERMUT[[i]] <- permute(matrixnetwork, 
 sample(vcount(matrixnetwork)))  
 }
 plot (BIPERMUT[[1]])
```

I try too, for permutation matrix, here I utilise only sample:

```
 N <- 7L
 set.seed(2023)
 R <- 100L
 BIboot2 <- vector("list", length = R)
 for(i in seq.int(R)) {
  indices <- sample(N, replace = TRUE)
  BIboot2[[i]] <- matrixnetwork
  }

plot (BIboot2[[1]])
degree(BIboot2[[1]], normalized = FALSE, loops = FALSE)
```

Help me find the best solution for permutation in 100x to matrixnetwork
...

I try

```
 boot_degree <- lapply(AIPERMUT, degree, normalized = FALSE, loops = 
 FALSE)
 degree_cool <- do.call("rbind", boot_degree)
```

but I need him to understand that a variable is allocated to different columns in each row, and he can always pull the same variable to a specific column
[image]

Comment: Some questions: 1. If all you are doing is permuting the rows/columns of a matrix, why do you need to convert it to a graph? 2. I see that you are computing degrees, however, degrees are invariant to vertex permutations, so nothing changes. In fact, all typical network properties are invariant to vertex permutation.

Comment: Where I do this? " If all you are doing is permuting the rows/columns of a matrix, why do you need to convert it to a graph?". 2- I'm trying to analyze the degree for 100 matrices I already have , and my cod is wrong. Because this I'm here hahaha... below an answer helped! Regarding the permutation of the matrix itself, I tried permuting it in 3 ways, can you see if it is correct? I added the codes here.

Comment: Your code is not readable. Please pay attention to proper formatting. If `p` is a permutation, e.g. `p <- sample(1:nrow(m))`, and `m` is a square matrix, you can permute it using `m[p,p]`. Do not use igraph if you just want to permute matrices.

Comment: I edit code. Sorry. But I don't understand how is de best form to do this permutation for matrixnetwork –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the results vector `boot_degree` before the `for` loop.

```
boot_degree <- vector("list", R)
for(i in seq.int(R)) {
  boot_degree[[i]] <- degree(g_boot_list[[i]], normalized = FALSE, loops = FALSE)
}
```

Another way is to `lapply` function `degree` to each member of `g_boot_list`.

```
boot_degree2 <- lapply(g_boot_list, degree, normalized = FALSE, loops = FALSE)

identical(boot_degree, boot_degree2)  # TRUE
```

Comment: After this, how I can do one t test with list? I try but dont run.

Comment: @AnaPaulaCastro What variables do you want to test? Each of the degrees vectors? Against what vector? Maybe an ANOVA test is your best option.

Comment: I want 1- find the degree of each node of every 100 matrices.
then 2- I want to compare the degree of each area resulting from the 100 matrices with a random network (an independent samples t-test). This random network not is in this code. But basically I want to compare the degree of 2 networks that were exchanged at 100 each. one being my network. and another created randomly

Comment: But I don't can access to degree for each node, becaus format list in this variable "boot_degree2". node correspond to the "columns" (there are 7 with a degree for each in each matrix). I need to take all 100 degrees of each node coming from the 100 matrices, and compare this specific node) which will have an average resulting from the 100 matrices) and compare it with another network that did the same thing

Comment: @AnaPaulaCastro Something like `boot_degree_df <- do.call(cbind, boot_degree) |> as.data.frame()`? To compute averages use `rowMeans` or `colMeans` on the resulting data.frame.

Comment: Hello, I have problem....I need him to understand that a variable is allocated to different columns in each row, and he can always pull the same variable to a specific column.  I add one print in this post.